# Is it possible to adjust the exposure of a webcam using Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, webcam, video-processing

I've written a program to use a webcam in Silverlight 4.  The only problem is that during the day my camera is massively overexposed.  Is there a way to adjust the exposure?

Here's some of my code just in case you want a general idea as to how I'm using my webcam.

```
        // Initialize the webcam
        captureSource = new CaptureSource();
        captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();

        // Fill the Viewport Rectangle with the VideoBrush
        var vidBrush = new VideoBrush();
        vidBrush.SetSource(captureSource);

        //ViewRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
        ViewRectangle.Fill = vidBrush;

        // Wire the VideoSink and the webcam together
        sink = new CaptureHandlingVideoSink { CaptureSource = captureSource };
       sink.Process += Process;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You can check the driver / settings of your webcam. Or you might want to reduce the brightness of the captured image as a post processing step. This works within some limits. Of course a totally overexposed image can't be corrected.

You can find a brightness and contrast modification algorithm in this article I've written: 
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/PicFx--Windows-Phone-Picture-Effects-Application--Part-1

Comment: Thanks Rene... I was busy reading your article on realtime face detection today, before I posted this question.  I just find that a bit bizarre that you answered this question... I mean there are six billion people on the planet, right?!?  I suppose only a few that work with webcams in Silverlight.  Anyway... back to work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, those settings are only available in the user config screen:

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/webcams/#config_settings

Comment: Not really. You can only select the default device there.